# ASP.NET MVC / If modelstate is invalid -> return a bootstrap alert

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

my question is: "How can I show a alert if the modelstate is invalid?"

I have a HomeController where I check if the ModelState.IsValid. I'm using a modal to create new items.

```
// GET: Project/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
            ProjectDto newProject = new ProjectDto();
            newProject.StartTime = DateTime.Now;

            var details = service.GetAllRequirementDetails();
            var list = new SelectList(details, "Id", "Title");
            var projects = service.GetAllProjects().ToList();

            var vm = new ProjectIndexViewModel(list, newProject);
            vm.Projects = projects;

            return View(vm);
        }
    }

    // POST: Project/Create/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CreateProjectViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var service = new Service1Client())
            {
                service.CreateProject(vm.NewProject);
                return RedirectToAction(RedirectString);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(RedirectString);
    }
```

I want to add

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">Something went wrong!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewBag if returned from same method or if model state returned redirect to next method then use TempData.

Here is example code.

```
// POST: Project/Create/
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult   Index(CreateProjectViewModel vm)
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
            service.CreateProject(vm.NewProject);
            return  RedirectToAction(RedirectString);
        }

    }
      ViewBag.Message = "Something went wrong";//if it is redirecting to some other action then use TempData
    return  View(vm);
}
```

In view part

```
  @if(!string.isNotNullorEmpty(ViewBag.Message){

 <div class="alert alert-danger"  role="alert">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">
    @ViewBag.Message</a>
    </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not posting your form via ajax, what you can do is to set a flag to indicate that the validation failed and in your page, check the value of that and execute your js code to show the bootstrap alert.

If `ModelState.IsValid` is false, you should not be redirecting, you should be returning the posted model to the same view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CreateProjectViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
            service.CreateProject(vm.NewProject);
            return RedirectToAction(RedirectString);
        }
    }
    ViewBag.DidValidationFail="Yes";
    return View(vm);
}
```

And in your Index view, render the div based on the value of this flag

```
@if (ViewBag.DidValidationFail == "Yes")
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="errorMsg" role="alert">
        <a href="#" class="alert-link">Something went wrong!</a>
    </div>
}
```

If you do not prefer to use the dynamic `ViewBag`, you may add a property to your viewmodel and set that property value and use that in your razor (Same as we did with ViewBag item)

Answer (score 0):

You can use put your message in the else part, and go back to your view (with the posted model) instead of redirecting. I've included a line that is useful to see what went wrong while debugging. That way you can customize your message according to the errors.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CreateProjectViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
            service.CreateProject(vm.NewProject);
            return RedirectToAction(RedirectString);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.error = "Something went wrong";
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

And in the view :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link">@ViewBag.error</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to show up if the modelstate is inValid. Now it is there the whole time.

Comment: That depends on how you have made your CSS. Otherwise you can put a test : @if (ViewBag.error != null) (like in Shyju's answer)

Comment: Thank you! This is very easy and great!